# Maven Android Project with Test Suite

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to set up a project with dependencies on ActionBarSherlock (4.0 RC1) and ViewPagerIndicator, I'm currently using Eclipse IDE, and I would like to be able to build and run an Android test project for this project. I had tell Eclipse to ignore the proguard and generate-sources goals to get it to stop giving me errors, it seems that was the solution for it, but I'm having a hard time confirming if that is still the correct solution. I've had moderate success with ABS thus far, I was able to deploy a package to the emulator that had an action bar, and Eclipse seems to know about the classes and resources in ABS. However, it doesn't know about the themes (like Theme.Sherlock.Light) and displays an error. I'm okay with that, except it means I can't run using Eclipse. But it doesn't seem to work for ViewPagerIndicator. And I keep running into random errors and it feels like  I'm just running around in a circle.

So I tried adding a test project (again..), so that I can test the project as I build it, to make sure it meets all my specifications at each step. But I can't seem to get that to work. If I could just get these 3 things and how to run the tests I should be able to debug other problems that are arising, but as it is now I can't even confirm where the problems lie. Most of my researching has yielded partial answers and out-of-date solutions.

Using:
ActionBarSherlock 4.0 RC1
ViewPagerIndicator 2.2.3
android-maven-plugin 3.1.1.99.0.6
Apache Maven 3.0.3
Eclipse Indigo
m2e 1.0.100.20110804-1717

Comment: I was lead to Gaug.es app, and have what appears to be a project with ABS, ViewPagerIndicator, android-maven-plugin, and test suite. I'm editing in TextMate though, because I don't want Eclipse to ruin it.

Comment: You should provide concrete error details like logcat, exception stack trace, etc for people look into and analyse your problem, instead of simply saying those three things doesn't work together and How do I fix it. Secondly, use right tool to do the right job, I don't see any benefits you can gain and helps on this by using a dummy text editor other than a IDE.

Comment: The point is that I tried many configurations have and extremely varied errors, but knew that other apps must require the same tools (+/- Eclipse). I didn't need a "how do you fix it", I needed the correct approach to configuring it all, which Gaug.es app provides. The point is, one approach to debugging such problems is to use command line tools instead of an IDE, but you still need to edit the code somehow. I was also led to IntelliJ IDEA CE, which isn't the official Android IDE, but it works a lot better with Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question on the maven-android-plugin Google group, and Manfred Moser pointed me to [Gaug.es app for Android](https://github.com/github/gauges-android). It has a set up for building the app with Maven, and has dependencies for ABS, ViewPagerIndicator, RoboGuice, Robotium, and a few others. It is set up to do unit tests with surefire and integration tests with instrumentation.

He also mentioned that he uses IntelliJ IDEA, which I thought I would try for myself (since Eclipse was giving me issues and TextMate is not even an IDE). The Community Edition has been serving well so far,it provides nicer (or easier to understand) integration with ant and maven, so I can specify my "clean package android:deploy" run configuration, for example.

If you're having similar issues, I would recommend taking a look at Gaug.es, it can be a little overbearing and do more than you want or should start off with. I can post the details of what I gathered from Gaug.es for my own app if anyone else is curious, but I thought I would note that my question is currently resolved, and how it was resolved.