# android + eclipse + maven + actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I read lots of things about actionbarsherlock, maven, android but none of the solution I've seen worked for me :(

I'm sure that I'm pretty close to the solution but I don't understand and I need some help :)

So here is my problem, I try to create an android maven project with a dependency to Actionbarsherlock.... It seems pretty easy but I've always thoses errors

```
[2013-01-16 18:10:28 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-01-16 18:10:28 - greennfc-samples] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-01-16 18:10:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;
[2013-01-16 18:10:50 - greennfc-samples] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;
```

Here is my configuration :

Eclipse Juno
M2e 1.2.0
ADT 21
Maven 3.0.4

Here is the parent pom :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.greennfc.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>greennfc</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Green NFC - Parent</name>
<description>Android Nfc library for an easer management of NFC features</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<url>https://github.com/binomed/greennfc</url>
<inceptionYear>2013</inceptionYear>

<!-- 
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/octo-online/robospice.git</connection>
    <url>git:ssh://git@github.com/octo-online/robospice.git</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/octo-online/robospice.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
 -->

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<issueManagement>
    <system>Github Issue Tracker</system>
    <url>https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/issues</url>
</issueManagement>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>JFG</id>
        <name>Jean-Francois Garreau</name>
        <email>jean.francois.garreau@binomed.fr</email>
    </developer>
</developers>

<!-- 
<mailingLists>
    <mailingList>
        <name>RoboSpice Forum/Mailinglist</name>
        <post>http://groups.google.com/group/robospice</post>
        <subscribe>http://groups.google.com/group/robospice/subscribe</subscribe>
        <unsubscribe>https://groups.google.com/group/robospice/subscribe</unsubscribe>
    </mailingList>
</mailingLists>

<ciManagement>
    <system>jenkins</system>
    <url>https://robospice.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Build%20RoboSpice/</url>
</ciManagement>
 -->

<modules>
    <!-- core library -->
    <module>greennfc-core</module>

    <!-- Base librairies elements -->
    <module>greennfc-filters</module>

    <!-- extensions -->

    <!-- Demo -->
    <module>greennfc-samples</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
    <android-platform.version>14</android-platform.version>
    <android-annotations.version>4.1.1.4</android-annotations.version>
    <android-support.version>r7</android-support.version>
    <android-maven-plugin.version>3.5.0</android-maven-plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
    <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
</properties>

<!-- TODO : remove this when android maven plugin 3.4.2 is out -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>oss.sonatype.org-jayway-snapshots</id>
        <name>Jayway OpenSource SNAPSHOTs on Sonatype.org</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/jayway-snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${android-annotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591811/ignoring-innerclasses-attribute-warning-is-killing-eclipse -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040788/how-to-elimate-the-maven-enforcer-plugin-goal-enforce-is-ignored-by-m2e-wa -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://commons.apache.org/lang/api</link>
                        <link>http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api</link>
                    </links>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- deploy artifacts to github for downloads -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>downloads-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <description>${project.version} release of ${project.name}</description>
                    <override>true</override>
                    <includeAttached>true</includeAttached>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- deploy javadoc and maven site to github -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
                <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <message>Creating site for ${project.version}</message>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>site</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <dependencyDetailsEnabled>true</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                                <dependencyLocationsEnabled>true</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </reportPlugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sign</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>performRelease</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.javadoc.skip>false</maven.javadoc.skip>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and here is the pom of my project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.greennfc.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>greennfc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

 <artifactId>greennfc-samples</artifactId>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
 <name>Green Nfc - Samples</name>
 <properties>
    <notificationcompat2.version>1.1.2</notificationcompat2.version>
    <actionbarsherlock.version>4.2.0</actionbarsherlock.version>
    <roboguice.version>2.0</roboguice.version>
    <robosherlock.version>1.4</robosherlock.version>
    <google.http.client.version>1.12.0-beta</google.http.client.version>
    <simplexmlserializer.version>2.6.6</simplexmlserializer.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.9</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Green Nfc dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.greennfc.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>greennfc-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other libs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>${android-support.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
      <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
      <version>${actionbarsherlock.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>${actionbarsherlock.version}</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>  

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android-platform.version}</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here what i try :

[Maven Android Project with Test Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591245/maven-android-project-with-test-suite)
http://v.zasadnyy.com/blog/abs-maven-eclipse-integration/

As actionbarsherlock project, I'm using the head of the git repository, I copied the library directory, pasted it in the same folder as my parent project and rename it according to {groupId}-{artifactId}-{version}

I'm really open to restart from scratch and find a way to do it right because i don't understand why it doesn't work... :(

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 15):

Here's how I fixed it. It's due to Maven trying to export its dependencies when Eclipse is also exporting its Android dependencies:

1. Project->Properties->Java Build Path
2. Go to the Order and Export tab.
3. Uncheck "Maven Dependencies" so they don't get double exported.
4. Clean and try to run it.
5. If it still doesn't work, also uncheck "Android Dependencies."

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea, and could cause other compile problems if you're relying on Maven dependencies elsewhere. Please do not blithely remove classpath containers from your classpath. Simply use the provided scope as Stephen recommends above.

Comment: The answer was in front of me for the whole time and I didn't see it until I read your answer. You helped me A LOT, and I thank you for that!

Comment: Although I agree with @RicardoGladwell, there are cases where this seems to be the only solution. Thank you!

Comment: @TomTasche the latest version of m2e-android on the master/snapshot update site should fix this issue, please see my answer above.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue using *Maven*, *Eclipse*, and *ActionBarSherlock*.
The problem is that the support library gets put into the build path twice, making the dexopt confused about the multiple declarations.

I was able to get rid of one of the places where dexopt was finding the support library by **changing** the `pom.xml` for *ActionBarSherlock* from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you clean the project after saving this change.

Answer (score 3):

You need to identify which dependencies in your pom.xml are including the classes that the Dalvik compiler is complaining about.

1. In eclipse, you can identify what jar the problematic class belongs to by Open Type (on mac Command-T).
2. Then you determine which transitive dependencies to those jars you have by looking up each direct dependency you have in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/). And peering into the projects pom.xml.
3. Once identified you need to add exclusion clauses to the corresponding dependency configuration in your project pom.xml.

project pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.hamcrest</artifactId>
                <groupId>hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There's a brute force way to do it as well. Just open up the project in eclipse, expand the 'Maven Dependencies' in project viewer, then add the exclusion clause to each direct dependency in your project pom one by one, each time hitting save. The android maven configuration plugin will recalculate the dependencies under 'Maven Dependencies' and you'll see the problematic jar disappear. Once you get all of them your Dalvik errors will disappear as well.

Answer (score 2):

I tried hard to make the ActionBarSherlock lib project work with Maven but I failed. Similar issues. So I removed maven dependencies in the lib project and use libs/android-support-v4.jar instead. Btw, the test folder is also deleted. Then I run my own project with refers to the lib project. Things went well.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to remove the jUnit/Hamcrest dependency from ABS's pom.xml, then had to delete the jUnit test class in the tests/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks every one for your answers, the things that worked for me was :

1. Remove supportv4 libs from actionbarsherlock
2. Comment the import of junit in actionbarsherlock project in order to avoid this generation